# Ember Data: Overriding Save method

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Hello Ember Data World,

I have been studying custom adapters attempting to figure out how to override the save method.

From my understanding, it seems like you need to do something like this:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.extend({ 
   save: function() { return this._super();}
})
```

However, when I attempted to invoke the save operation on my model object using:

```
model.save()
```

The store gets invoked directly and not my adapter custom code.

Has anyone attempted to do this before?

**I am able to call the find method using the following code in the same adapter**

```
findQuery: function(store, type, query) {
        //debugger;
        console.log("findQuery: Custom adapter called!");

            return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey), 'GET', { data: query });
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`save` is actually defined on the record, not the adapter.  If you felt like overriding it you would do so in your model definition.

Here's an example of that:

```
App.Color = DS.Model.extend({
    color: DS.attr(),

    save: function(){
      alert('save');
    }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/497/edit

Now if you felt like overriding what save eventually calls on the adapter you would need to update one of three methods, `createRecord`, `updateRecord`, `deleteRecord`.  They are pretty self explanatory in what they each should do when save is called.  You would then follow a pattern such as you did above:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter= DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  updateRecord: function(){
    alert('update record');
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/498/edit

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference!!