# Adding custom params to Ember Data model.save() method

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

i've been using Ember and the experience has been awesome so far. I'm now exploring Ember Data - specifically in extending RESTAdapter and modifying model.save() behavior.

Right now when I create a user using `var user = this.store.createRecord('user', {name:"bob"}`, then save the record using `user.save()`, a POST is executed to `http://localhost:8080/api/users`

I simply want to add a custom param to the POST URL, like so:

`http://localhost:8080/api/users?inviteCode=abc123`

This custom param should be set dynamically like `user.save('abc123')`. However, i'm at a loss at what code to modify to support this behavior.

I know i probably have to extend my User model's save method as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766993/ember-data-overriding-save-method), but how should i proceed from there?